# How to change the width of NormalPeoplePicker dropdown

Tags: office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react

I'm using default example of NormalPeoplePicker from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/peoplepicker#IPeoplePickerProps.
When the dropdown displays it cuts off longer items (example: 'Anny Lundqvist, Junior Manager of Soft..'). How do I make it wider, so that the full item's text displays?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Checkbox } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Checkbox';
import { IPersonaProps } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Persona';
import { IBasePickerSuggestionsProps, NormalPeoplePicker, ValidationState } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Pickers';
import { people, mru } from '@uifabric/example-data';

const suggestionProps: IBasePickerSuggestionsProps = {
  suggestionsHeaderText: 'Suggested People',
  mostRecentlyUsedHeaderText: 'Suggested Contacts',
  noResultsFoundText: 'No results found',
  loadingText: 'Loading',
  showRemoveButtons: true,
  suggestionsAvailableAlertText: 'People Picker Suggestions available',
  suggestionsContainerAriaLabel: 'Suggested contacts',
};

const checkboxStyles = {
  root: {
    marginTop: 10,
  },
};

export const PeoplePickerNormalExample: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [delayResults, setDelayResults] = React.useState(false);
  const [isPickerDisabled, setIsPickerDisabled] = React.useState(false);
  const [mostRecentlyUsed, setMostRecentlyUsed] = React.useState<IPersonaProps[]>(mru);
  const [peopleList, setPeopleList] = React.useState<IPersonaProps[]>(people);

  const picker = React.useRef(null);

  const onFilterChanged = (
    filterText: string,
    currentPersonas: IPersonaProps[],
    limitResults?: number,
  ): IPersonaProps[] | Promise<IPersonaProps[]> => {
    if (filterText) {
      let filteredPersonas: IPersonaProps[] = filterPersonasByText(filterText);

      filteredPersonas = removeDuplicates(filteredPersonas, currentPersonas);
      filteredPersonas = limitResults ? filteredPersonas.slice(0, limitResults) : filteredPersonas;
      return filterPromise(filteredPersonas);
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  };

  const filterPersonasByText = (filterText: string): IPersonaProps[] => {
    return peopleList.filter(item => doesTextStartWith(item.text as string, filterText));
  };

  const filterPromise = (personasToReturn: IPersonaProps[]): IPersonaProps[] | Promise<IPersonaProps[]> => {
    if (delayResults) {
      return convertResultsToPromise(personasToReturn);
    } else {
      return personasToReturn;
    }
  };

  const returnMostRecentlyUsed = (currentPersonas: IPersonaProps[]): IPersonaProps[] | Promise<IPersonaProps[]> => {
    return filterPromise(removeDuplicates(mostRecentlyUsed, currentPersonas));
  };

  const onRemoveSuggestion = (item: IPersonaProps): void => {
    const indexPeopleList: number = peopleList.indexOf(item);
    const indexMostRecentlyUsed: number = mostRecentlyUsed.indexOf(item);

    if (indexPeopleList >= 0) {
      const newPeople: IPersonaProps[] = peopleList
        .slice(0, indexPeopleList)
        .concat(peopleList.slice(indexPeopleList + 1));
      setPeopleList(newPeople);
    }

    if (indexMostRecentlyUsed >= 0) {
      const newSuggestedPeople: IPersonaProps[] = mostRecentlyUsed
        .slice(0, indexMostRecentlyUsed)
        .concat(mostRecentlyUsed.slice(indexMostRecentlyUsed + 1));
      setMostRecentlyUsed(newSuggestedPeople);
    }
  };

  const onDisabledButtonClick = (): void => {
    setIsPickerDisabled(!isPickerDisabled);
  };

  const onToggleDelayResultsChange = (): void => {
    setDelayResults(!delayResults);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <NormalPeoplePicker
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-bind
        onResolveSuggestions={onFilterChanged}
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-bind
        onEmptyInputFocus={returnMostRecentlyUsed}
        getTextFromItem={getTextFromItem}
        pickerSuggestionsProps={suggestionProps}
        className={'ms-PeoplePicker'}
        key={'normal'}
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-bind
        onRemoveSuggestion={onRemoveSuggestion}
        onValidateInput={validateInput}
        removeButtonAriaLabel={'Remove'}
        inputProps={{
          onBlur: (ev: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => console.log('onBlur called'),
          onFocus: (ev: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => console.log('onFocus called'),
          'aria-label': 'People Picker',
        }}
        componentRef={picker}
        onInputChange={onInputChange}
        resolveDelay={300}
        disabled={isPickerDisabled}
      />
      <Checkbox
        label="Disable People Picker"
        checked={isPickerDisabled}
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-bind
        onChange={onDisabledButtonClick}
        styles={checkboxStyles}
      />
      <Checkbox
        label="Delay Suggestion Results"
        defaultChecked={delayResults}
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-bind
        onChange={onToggleDelayResultsChange}
        styles={checkboxStyles}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

function doesTextStartWith(text: string, filterText: string): boolean {
  return text.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase()) === 0;
}

function removeDuplicates(personas: IPersonaProps[], possibleDupes: IPersonaProps[]) {
  return personas.filter(persona => !listContainsPersona(persona, possibleDupes));
}

function listContainsPersona(persona: IPersonaProps, personas: IPersonaProps[]) {
  if (!personas || !personas.length || personas.length === 0) {
    return false;
  }
  return personas.filter(item => item.text === persona.text).length > 0;
}

function convertResultsToPromise(results: IPersonaProps[]): Promise<IPersonaProps[]> {
  return new Promise<IPersonaProps[]>((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(results), 2000));
}

function getTextFromItem(persona: IPersonaProps): string {
  return persona.text as string;
}

function validateInput(input: string): ValidationState {
  if (input.indexOf('@') !== -1) {
    return ValidationState.valid;
  } else if (input.length > 1) {
    return ValidationState.warning;
  } else {
    return ValidationState.invalid;
  }
}

/**
 * Takes in the picker input and modifies it in whichever way
 * the caller wants, i.e. parsing entries copied from Outlook (sample
 * input: "Aaron Reid <aaron>").
 *
 * @param input The text entered into the picker.
 */
function onInputChange(input: string): string {
  const outlookRegEx = /<.*>/g;
  const emailAddress = outlookRegEx.exec(input);

  if (emailAddress && emailAddress[0]) {
    return emailAddress[0].substring(1, emailAddress[0].length - 1);
  }

  return input;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Component which renders suggestion list have fixed width of 180px. Take a look at [PeoplePickerItemSuggestion.styles.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/cbc0b9a2f9b569eeabd7bba3812002edcca948e8/packages/react-internal/src/components/pickers/PeoplePicker/PeoplePickerItems/PeoplePickerItemSuggestion.styles.ts#L44).

What you can do is to modify this class `.ms-PeoplePicker-Persona`:

```
.ms-PeoplePicker-Persona {
   width: 260px; // Or what ever you want
}
```

**UPDATE** - *Solution from comments*

Change `width` trough `styles` *property* of *PeoplePickerItemSuggestion Component*

```
const onRenderSuggestionsItem = (personaProps, suggestionsProps) => (
  <PeoplePickerItemSuggestion 
    personaProps={personaProps} 
    suggestionsProps={suggestionsProps} 
    styles={{ personaWrapper: { width: '100%' }}}
  />
);

<NormalPeoplePicker
  onRenderSuggestionsItem={onRenderSuggestionsItem}
  pickerCalloutProps={{ calloutWidth: 500 }}
  ...restProps
/>
```

Working [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/jOrBObd?editors=0010)

For more information how to customize components read [Component Styling](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/wiki/Component-Styling).

Comment: thanks @marko-savic. it worked great. I also found another solution see - https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/11222 - to override onRenderSuggestionsItem. BTW thanks for the component styling links. it's pretty overwhelming to find your way through picker props and style hierarchy.

Comment: @Marek Yeah I know for that approach. Actually they recommended to change style trough `styles`. I'll update my answer for future readers. Please mark it as a solution, thank you!